# How to draw a circle plot the LinearColorMapper using python Bokeh

Tags: python, plot, bokeh

With the following code,

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show, output_file
from bokeh.sampledata.iris import flowers

colormap = {'setosa': 'red', 'versicolor': 'green', 'virginica': 'blue'}
colors = [colormap[x] for x in flowers['species']]

p = figure(title = "Iris Morphology")
p.xaxis.axis_label = 'Petal Length'
p.yaxis.axis_label = 'Petal Width'

p.circle(flowers["petal_length"], flowers["petal_width"],
         color=colors, fill_alpha=0.2, size=10)

output_file("iris.html", title="iris.py example")

show(p)
```

I can make a circle plot where I color the species:

[image]

But what I want to do is to color all the point based on range of 
value in `petal_length`.

I tried this code but fail:

```
from bokeh.models import LinearColorMapper
exp_cmap = LinearColorMapper(palette='Viridis256', low = min(flowers["petal_length"]), high = max(flowers["petal_length"]))

p.circle(flowers["petal_length"], flowers["petal_width"], 
         fill_color = {'field'  : flowers["petal_lengh"], 'transform' : exp_cmap})

output_file("iris.html", title="iris.py example")

show(p)
```

And also in the final desired plot, how can I put the color bar that
show the range of values and the assigned value. Something like this:

[image]

I'm using `Python 2.7.13`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To answer your first part, there was a small typo (`petal_lengh` instead of `petal_length`) but more importantly, using the `bokeh.ColumnDataSource` will solve your problem (I tried to do it without `CDS` and only got column errors):

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show, output_file
from bokeh.sampledata.iris import flowers  
from bokeh.models import LinearColorMapper
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource

p = figure(title = "Iris Morphology")
p.xaxis.axis_label = "Petal Length"
p.yaxis.axis_label = "Petal Width"

source = ColumnDataSource(flowers)

exp_cmap = LinearColorMapper(palette="Viridis256", 
                             low = min(flowers["petal_length"]), 
                             high = max(flowers["petal_length"]))

p.circle("petal_length", "petal_width", source=source, line_color=None,
        fill_color={"field":"petal_length", "transform":exp_cmap})

# ANSWER SECOND PART - COLORBAR
# To display a color bar you'll need to import 
# the `bokeh.models.ColorBar` class and pass it your mapper.
from bokeh.models import ColorBar
bar = ColorBar(color_mapper=exp_cmap, location=(0,0))
p.add_layout(bar, "left")

show(p)
```

[image]

See also: https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/blob/master/examples/plotting/file/color_data_map.py

Answer (score 2):

The colormapper transform refers to a *column name* and does not accept actual literal lists of data. So all the data needs to be in a Bokeh `ColumDataSource` and the plotting funcs all need to refer to the column names. Fortunately this is straightforward:

```
p.circle("petal_length", "petal_width", source=flowers, size=20,
         fill_color = {'field': 'petal_length', 'transform': exp_cmap})
```

[image]

Directions for legends outside the plot area are documented here:

https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/styling.html#outside-the-plot-area